# berkeley db partial match

Tags: c, berkeley-db

Is there any way with berkeley db 5.x C API to get 
all the records with a key matching a prefix ?

(without scanning the entire database)

Maybe with a Btree prefix comparison custom callback ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two parts to the solution.  First, you need to use a custom key comparison function.

```
dbp->set_bt_compare(dbp, cmp_fn);
```

In the comparison function, make it so that the keys with the same prefix are sorted next to each other in the database.  This might be as simple as a bunch of less-than compares, so that something like `0x000000000000000000000001` is less than `0x000000000000000000000002`.

To do the search, open a cursor and do a `cursor->get()` with a `DB_SET_RANGE` flag.  Set your starting key to be at the beginning of the prefix range.  Say, if you were looking for keys with the prefix `0x1138`, you'd set the key to `0x113800000000000000000000`.  Then keep calling `cursor->get()` with `DB_NEXT`.  When you see a key that doesn't have the `0x1138` prefix, you're done.

This technique does not have to scan the entire database, as the initial `DB_SET_RANGE` call starts the cursor in the right place, and the records are all right next to each other in the tree.